# Does using crypto_stream_xor allow listeners to forge crypto_secretbox messages?

Tags: encryption, libsodium, forgery

I understand that NaCl's `crypto_stream` and `crypto_stream_xor` don't do any authentication like `crypto_secretbox` does. Does using them allow listeners to *forge* `crypto_secretbox` messages for any key you use them with?

I'm worried about a known plaintext attack. If I use `crypto_stream_xor` to encrypt a bunch of zeroes, the listener now has the full keystream for whatever nonce I just used. I think they can use the first 32 bytes of that as a `crypto_onetimeauth` key to forge valid authenticators for `crypto_secretbox` messages, with whatever plaintext they want (up to the length of the zeroes I encrypted, minus 32).

If that's right, then using `crypto_stream_xor` seems to break authenticity just as badly as nonce reuse does. The NaCl/libsodium documentation is pretty clear about saying "never reuse a nonce with the same key", but there's nothing in there about "never use `crypto_stream_xor` with a key that you also use for `crypto_secretbox`."

Comment: Related [Why can't I use the same key for encryption and MAC?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/37880/why-cant-i-use-the-same-key-for-encryption-and-mac)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`crypto_secretbox` uses the first 32 bytes of XSalsa20 output as the key for Poly1305. Thus you are correct that using `crypto_stream_xor` on a known plaintext will reveal the authentication-key used by `crypto_secretbox`, allowing forgeries under that key and nonce.

Not using a key for multiple purposes is a general crypto design principle. Perhaps that's why the authors of NaCl didn't think of explicitly warning about this pitfall.